# Google App Scripts timing out on deleting columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a script that deletes rows where the date is in the past but as the spreadsheet has grown its starting to time out. Can anyone suggest how to make this faster as I understand that we have a hard set limit of 6 mins for timeouts

```
function approveRequests() {

  // Initialising
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var scheduleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combined");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


  var pastSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Left");
  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();

  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];

    // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") ||
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") ||
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "ABCDEF") 
      ) continue;

     for(var i = sheet.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--){

    // Check if the value is a valid date
       // 15 is for Col O
    var dateCell = sheet.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
    if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
      var today = new Date();
      var test = new Date(dateCell);

      // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
      if(test < today){

        var rangeToMove = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        pastSheet.getRange(pastSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(rangeToMove);
        sheet.deleteRow(i);

      }
    }
     }

  } // end of loop


}

// Check is a valid date
function isValidDate(value) {
  var dateWrapper = new Date(value);
  return !isNaN(dateWrapper.getDate());
}
```

Comment: I'd sort reverse by date, then do a loop that just goes down and checks the dates starting at row 1 until it finds the first entry in the past (x) and then deletes rows x to end of sheet. Deleting one row at a time is a really inefficient way to do this.

Comment: You declared sheet twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function approveRequests() {
  var excl=['ABCDEF','GHIJKL'];//excluded sheeets
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var pastSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Left");
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var tdv=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).valueOf();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var sh=shts[i];
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var d=0;//sh delete counter
    if(excl.indexOf(sh.getName())>-1) {continue;}
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {//assumed one header row
    if(isDate(vA[i][14]) && new Date(vA[i][14]).valueOf()<tdv) {
      pastSheet.appendRow(vA[i]);
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+1);
      d++;
    }                            }
  } 
}

// Check is a valid date
function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

Thanks to @Christoph  for this: `return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');`

[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for this - When I try to run the script - I get Could not connect to serverDismiss. It looks to run then times out and can't find any logging available

Comment: not sure why this wouldn't work but the script runs and nothing happens :( Can't see anything in the logs

Comment: To go any further will require me to have access to your data.  Please don't share any private data.